# Javascript function draw

Tags: javascript

```
var random = randomNumber(1, 7);
var Block = createSprite(200, 0);
var Blocks = createGroup();
Blocks.add(Block);
Blocks.setAnimationEach(random.toString());
createEdgeSprites();
function draw() {
  background("white");
  Move("down", 4, 1);
  Move2("right", 4, 0, "left");
  Move2("left", -4, 0, "right");
  if (Blocks.isTouching(bottomEdge)) {
    var Block = createSprite(200, 0);
    Blocks.add(Block);
    Blocks.setAnimationEach(randomNumber(1, 7).toString());
  }
  if (Blocks.isTouching(edges)) {
    Blocks.collide(edges);
  }
  drawSprites();
}
function Move(Key, Velocity, Velocity2) {
  if (keyDown(Key)) {
      Block.velocityY = Velocity;
    } else {
    Block.velocityY = Velocity2;
  }
}
function Move2(Key, Velocity, Velocity2, Key2) {
  if (keyDown(Key)) {
      Block.velocityX = Velocity;
    } else if ((!keyDown(Key2))) {
      Block.velocityX = Velocity2;
    }
}
```

My issue is with

```
if (Blocks.isTouching(bottomEdge)) {
    var Block = createSprite(200, 0);
    Blocks.add(Block);
    Blocks.setAnimationEach(randomNumber(1, 7).toString());
  }
```

That code is basically for when a piece touches the ground, a new piece is made with a random Animation, that is the shape. I know I have to fix other stuff, but I know how to fix it. The thing I don't know how to do is set an animation once? Is there a code for that, because it constantly randomly changes the animation because the function draw() runs multiple times. But if I put it outside of that function, it only runs in the beginning of the program. Should I like push my sprite back up a little afterwards? I can't use const and I don't even know how to use it. Each time a sprite touches the ground, I want a new sprite to made and that animation is only set once. My biggest issue is that, I know there are other issues in that segment, but I can fix it myself

Comment: What Javascript library are you using? Are you working in a specific environment? This doesn't look like vanilla Javascript, so it will be difficult for anyone to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure? I'm a beginner programming just using game lab on code.org if that helps?